# Google Certified beacon partners?

Tags: eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I recently read about "Google certified Eddystone beacon partners".

How does one get certified? is there any criteria, test, beacon deployment?

Here is the link for the same: https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone#certified_beacon_partners

Any information will be appriciated. Thank you